# Elements of the Viewport EXTJS are not clickable

Tags: extjs, viewport

I am reading the book "MasteringExtjs" and Chapter 3 we created a ViewPort
Ext.create ('Packt.view.MyViewport'), the ViewPort is shown, but the elements (buttons, menus) are not clickable.

[ViewPort Code](http://goo.gl/ymxtwY)

[Login Controller](https://github.com/loiane/masteringextjs/blob/extjs-4.2.1883/app/controller/Login.js)

Comment: Do you have a live hosted version of this running anywhere publicly accessible?

And for the first debugging step, I'd add console logs to the first line of every function in the Login controller to see if they're even getting called when you click the buttons in question. If they are, it's a logic problem in the function. If they aren't, it's something weird with the view or the event handling.

Comment: Here is a picture . Note that the buttons and menus are disabled
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2lvzql5.jpg

Comment: Wow I guess anyone can write a book these days, just clicking on a few files I can see terrible ExtJS/Javascript practices.  Ones that I keep seeing in questions on here that cause the problems that they are seeing.  I am guessing `.mask()` is being called somewhere.  It could be an Ext component or the `body` being masked.

Comment: I'm afraid a screenshot doesn't help diagnose the problem in this case.